# Write data to file in columns (Fortran)

Tags: file-io, formatting, fortran, fortran90

I need to write some data to file in Fortran 90. How should I use `WRITE (*,*) input` to have the values grouped in **columns**? `WRITE` always puts a `new line` after each call, that's the problem.

code example:

```
open (unit = 4, file = 'generated_trajectories1.dat', form='formatted')

do time_nr=0, N
   write (4,*) dble(time_nr)*dt, initial_traj(time_nr)
end do
```

And now the point is to have it written in separate columns.

Comment: Can you be more specific @Alex? You want to have what in separate columns? Do you want an output file containing `N` rows and two columns, one for `dble(time_nr)*dt` and one for `initial_traj(time_nr)`? Or do you want an output file with one row and `2*N` columns?

Comment: Please source the declarations so that we can suggest appropriate formats.  reals?  The examples in the answers of I formats won't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use implied DO loops to write values as single records. Compare the following two examples:

```
integer :: i

do i=1,10
   write(*,'(2I4)') i, 2*i
end do
```

It produces:

```
1   2
2   4
3   6
...
```

Using implied DO loops it can rewritten as:

```
integer :: i

write(*, '(10(2I4))') (i, 2*i, i=1,10)
```

This one produces:

```
1   2   2   4   3   6   ...
```

If the number of elements is not fixed at compile time, you can either use the `<n>` extension (not supported by `gfortran`):

```
write(*, '(<n>(2I4))') (i, 2*i, i=1,n)
```

It takes the number of repetitions of the `(2I4)` edit descriptor from the value of the variable `n`. In GNU Fortran you can first create the appropriate edit descriptor using internal files:

```
character(len=20) :: myfmt

write(myfmt, '("(",I0,"(2I4))")') n
write(*, fmt=myfmt) (i, 2*i, i=1,n)
```

Of course, it also works with list directed output (that is output with format of `*`):

```
write(*, *) (i, 2*i, i=1,10)
```

Comment: While gfortan doesn't support the <n> extension, it does support using * to designate an flexible number of format items.  This feature, unlimited format item, is part of the Fortran 2008 standard.

Comment: @M.S.B. I didn't know about that feature in F2008 - very welcome addition, really.

Comment: @HristoIliev, If I have real numbers to print then how to go about. Regarding formatting, as '(10(2I4))', this wasn't working.

Comment: @lavkush, the corresponding edit descriptors for real numbers are `E` and `F` - see [here](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Edit+descriptors). `G` can be used to automatically select between `E` or `F` based on the value to be printed and the width of the output field.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on the <n> extension - works perfectly with the intel compiler.

Answer (score 4):

This really depends on what data you are trying to write to file (i.e. whether you have a scalar within a loop or an array...). Can you include a description of this in your question?

If your are trying to write a scalar multiple times to the same row then try using *non-advancing I/O*, passing the keyword argument `advance="no"` to the write statement, e.g.

```
integer :: x

do x = 1,10
  write(*, fmt='(i4,1x)', advance="no") x
end do
```

However, be aware of a suprise with [non-advancing I/O](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~szymansk/OOF90/bugs.html#3).

Comment: it is all done in a loop, so non-advancing is a way to do it. But instead of nice bunch of numbers in columns I get some binary-like text. So there is something wrong with formatting I suppose. GEdit wouldn't even open the file.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of your code? How data is written to file is determined by the arguments passed to the open command, without your code it is impossible to tell exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your answer to Chris's question.   If you want a single line, then you will have to use non-advancing IO as described by Chris.  Without this, with multiple formatted write statement you will always get multiple lines.

Also, you will likely need to use formatted IO instead of list-directed (*) IO.  The rules are loose for list-directed IO.  Different compilers may produce different output.  With many output items, line breaks are likely to keep the output lines from being too long.

Here a format that should work if all of your variables are reals:

```
write (4, '( *(2X, ES14.6) )', advance="no" )
```

Answer (score 0):

how about the good old $ edit descriptor:

```
write(*, fmt='(i4,$)') x
```

remember to do a write(*,*) after your loop...

Comment: Nothing like that is in the standard Fortran.

Comment: yes one of those extensions that is so pervasive you forget its an extension.