# How to read data from multiple files and write into columns of a single file

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm completely new in Fortran and I need to write some relatively simple codes.

I have some files (various, for example 200 files); each file for the specific node, with some simplification, each file contains:

```
T(i), X(i)
```

these are my input and I want to have an output file contain:

```
T(i) X(i)1 X(i)2 ... X(i)n
```

the problem is that I can't separate data in different columns of output file, they comes all after each other in 1 column.

My code is :

```
PROGRAM Output

implicit none
integer ::nn,n,i,j,l
real,dimension(:),allocatable::t,x,y,z
character(len=10)::TD 

open(11,file='outputX.txt')
allocate (t(1000),x(1000),y(1000),z(1000)) 

n=5                  ! Number of Files
nn=50                ! Number of Rows in each File
 Do i=1,n            ! loop for opening different files 
   write(TD,10)i 
   write(*,*)TD 
   open(1,file=TD) 

      Do l=1,nn      ! loop for reading rows in each file
        read(1,*)t(j),x(j)
        write(11,*)x(j) !!!! This is my PROBLEM, all the data shows in
                               ! one column, I want each file in separately
      Enddo

 Enddo

    10  format('100',i3.3,'') 

    deallocate(x,y,z,t) 
    END PROGRAM Output
```

The output I get is like this :

```
11
12
13
21
22
23
31
32
33
```

But in fact I want :

```
11    21   31
12    22   32
13    23   33
```

Comment: Each `write` as you have it will produce a single line ("record").  You need to combine your writing of various values into a single output statement.  Like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28691924) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12002620).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code

```
 Do i=1,n            ! loop for opening different files 
   write(TD,10)i 
   write(*,*)TD 
   open(1,file=TD) 
   Do l=1,nn      ! loop for reading rows in each file
     read(1,*)t(j),x(j)
     write(11,*)x(j) !!!! This is my PROBLEM, all the data shows in
                               ! one column, I want each file in separately
  End do
End do
```

The index `j` is completely undefined. You should put `j=1` or `0` and `j=j+1` somewhere inside the loop.

The other issue is your output. You are reading the files in sequence. It is very hard to print each file into a separate column. A separate row for each file is easy:

```
write(11,*) x(1:nn)
```

**after** the inner loop.

Or with finer control and avoiding a line wrap

```
write(11,'999(g0,1x)') x(1:nn)
```

(g0 is a general edit descriptor which uses only the necessary width). This will only work if you fix the `j` issue I mentioned above!

To put it into separate columns you must

1. Open all files at the same time, then read from each of them and print the read data in a single write command.

or

2. Store all the data from all files into separate columns in a 2D array and print the 2D array afterwards.

Comment: I get the answer by this :
 
Read(1,*)(t(j),x(j),j=1,nn)
Write(11,200)(x(j),j=1,nn)

And as you say in the rows, not columns.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

So what I got is `x(1) belongs to 11`, `x(2) belongs to 12`, `x(3) belongs to 13` and so on, isn't it? You could try this one:

```
write(11,100) x(j), x(j+3), x(j+6)
100 format(1X,11F20.4,11F20.4,11F20.4)
```

Comment: I woudn't show the FORMAT statement as an example of modern code to beginners.

Comment: @VladimirF: You comment too much on what someone has done. If you wouldn't like to show the FORMAT statement, maybe you could also help the author please by answering him... Yes, thanks for your suggestion, I've already deleted the former answer.

Comment: @VladimirF: I think you also didn't read the author's problem above correctly. He even wrote the FORMAT statement on his code.

Comment: The comment to the OP is necessary. That SHOULD be deleted. I try to suggest how to improve your answer. Yes, it is not that difficult to answer myself. I am giving chance also to new users and trying to help, but thanks for feedback, not anymore to you if you mind that.

Comment: @VladimirF: Regarding to OP, I always follow your suggestion even on my previous postings. I don't doubt you, since indeed I should delete my former answer and I've done it. The thing is you said, you wouldn't show FORMAT statement to the beginner (in this case it's the author), even you didn't see that the author himself wrote using FORMAT statement. That's why I'm trying to help him with using the FORMAT statement. I know for sure it not subjected to Modern Fortran. But our aims in this site are to help each other REGARDING to his/her questions, right? Anyway, thanks also for you.

Answer (score 0):

The 2D array... for this problem it is backwards
But it should give you some help... (Hopefully)

```
PROGRAM Output
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER              :: nfiles = 5
INTEGER, PARAMETER              :: nrows  = 50
integer                         :: iFile, iRow   !File and row counter/#
real,dimension(:,:),allocatable :: t,x,y,z       !The are now 2D
INTEGER,dimension(nFiles)       :: lFile         !logical file indexed by file#
LOGICAL,dimension(nFiles)       :: Open4Biz      !logical for closing
character(len=10)::TD                            !Unsure about this

open(11,file='outputX.txt')
allocate (t(iRow,iFile),x(iRow,iFile),y(iRow,iFile),z(iRow,iFile)) 

Open4Biz(:) = .FALSE.                            !Initialize

!n=5                  ! Number of Files              ^^Moved up/renamed^^
!nn=50                ! Number of Rows in each File  ^^Moved up/renamed^^
 Files_Loop1: Do iFile = 1, nFiles     !I think that the loop identifier is std f95 (std ifort anyhow)
   write(TD,10) iFile          !Unsure about this
   write(*,*)TD 
   lFile(iFile) = 10+iFile
   open(lFile(iFile),file=TD)  !Probably put in some logic if the file is not found
   Open4Biz(iFile) = .TRUE.
 ENDDO Files_Loop1

 Rows_Loop: Do iRow = 1, nn                !The loops are backwards from normal
   Files_Loop2: Do iFile = 1, nFiles
     read(lFile(iFile),*) t(iRow, iFile), x(iRow, iFile)
   Enddo Files_Loop2
   write(11,*) x(iRow,:)
 Enddo Rows_Loop

10  format('100',i3.3,'')

667  CONTINUE                         !This is label to 'jump to' from a bad open
Files_Loop3: Do iFile = 1, nFiles
  IF(Open4Biz(iFile) CLOSE(lFile(iFile))
ENDDO Files_Open_Loop

IF(ALLOCATED(X)) deallocate(x) 
IF(ALLOCATED(Y)) deallocate(y) 
IF(ALLOCATED(Z)) deallocate(z) 
IF(ALLOCATED(T)) deallocate(t)
END PROGRAM Output
```